# List of files and directories after uploading ASP.NET MVC app to my site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, deployment

Hi 
 I want to deploy my first ASP.NET MVC 5 application. To do that I published the solution (publish method: file system) and transferred the files to the server by Filezilla. When I visit the site I have a list of my files instead of a working application:
[image]

What am I missing?

**EDIT**:
I wrote a message to hosting support and they replied that ASP.NET applications don't work on their servers. Case closed.

Comment: What web server are you using to serve the files? IIS?

Comment: I don't know. I bought a hosting some time ago, but I'm not an expert in this matter. I have working WordPress and PHP sites there. How can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

I think
in IIS you have directory listing allowed and you do not have a properly configured default document

Comment: It works on localhost, so I think that's not the case.